# Olingo V4 Annotations not getting reflected in $metadata

Tags: java, apache, odata, metadata, olingo

I have implemented Odata V4 service using Olingo. I am trying to include
**Aggregation.ApplySupported** annotation to my service. However the annotation term value is blank in my $metadata document. Below is my code snippet

```
List<CsdlAnnotation> list = new ArrayList<CsdlAnnotation>();
CsdlAnnotation annotationAttribute = new CsdlAnnotation();
annotationAttribute.setTerm("Aggregation.ApplySupported");
annotationAttribute.setExpression(new CsdlConstantExpression(CsdlConstantExpression.ConstantExpressionType.String, "true"));
list.add(annotationAttribute);
entityContainer.setAnnotations(list);
```

**$metadata**

```
<EntityContainer Name="myContainer">
   <!-- .....sets -->
  <Annotation>   <!-- term is blank -->
     <String>true</String>
  </Annotation>
</EntityContainer>
```

Can't figure out whats I am missing on.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override **getTerm** method in your provider.

```
@Override
    public CsdlTerm getTerm(final FullQualifiedName termName) throws ODataException {
        return new CsdlTerm().setAppliesTo(Arrays.asList("EntityContainer"))
                .setName("ApplySupported");
    }
```

See example here: https://apache.googlesource.com/olingo-odata4/+/master/lib/server-core/src/test/java/org/apache/olingo/server/core/serializer/xml/MetadataDocumentXmlSerializerTest.java